LinAlgError: Array must not contain infs or NaNs
I am trying to put it in VAR to forecast...
data_n = yf.download("SPY",start="2022-09-01",end="2024-08-20",interval="1D")
data_n = data_n[["Close","High","Volume"]]

#data = np.exp(data)
#data.to_csv("DF.csv")


data = data_n.copy()

def calculate_rsi(data, window=14):
    delta = data['Close'].diff()
    gain = (delta.where(delta > 0, 0)).rolling(window=window).mean()
    loss = (-delta.where(delta < 0, 0)).rolling(window=window).mean()
    rs = gain / loss
    rsi = 100 - (100 / (1 + rs))
    return rsi



data["sma_8"]=data_n.Close.rolling(8).mean()
data["sma_13"]=data_n.Close.rolling(13).mean()
data['rsi_14'] = calculate_rsi(data)
data['ema12'] = data_n['Close'].ewm(span=4, adjust=False).mean()

data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)

I have downloaded data and stored it, I am trying to do Cointegration Test.
The matrix is not positive definite so I did this:
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_spd_matrix

from numpy import inf


data = data.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)

data = data.dropna()

data = data.fillna(1e-10)

def make_positive_definite(matrix):
    sym_matrix = (matrix + matrix.T) / 2
    
    min_eig = np.min(np.real(np.linalg.eigvals(sym_matrix)))
    if min_eig < 0:
        sym_matrix -= 10 * min_eig * np.eye(*sym_matrix.shape)
    
    return sym_matrix

data_pos = make_positive_definite(data)

but error: LinAlgError: Array must not contain infs or NaNs
I have tried nearly everything and I do not understand why it is not working.

matrix + matrix.T almost always give you a lot of NaN when matrix is a dataframe. The reason being the index and the columns are different. In your case, the index are the dates, while the columns are the features, e.g. sma_8, sma_13, etc.

Another thing, matrix + matrix.T only gives a symmetric matrix, not _positive definite.  you probably want to do matrix@matrix.T` to obtain a positive definite matrix.

It looks like the error is arising because you're trying to add two matrices, matrix + matrix.T, that have incompatible shapes for addition. In this case, matrix is of shape (480, 7) and matrix.T is (7, 480). Matrix addition requires the operands to have the same shape.
Also as @QuangHoang mentioned, to get positive definite matrix use np.matmul(matrix, matrix.T) or matrix@matrix.T
